# Use expression in access report textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS access report that I want to run using a linked excel table (so i cannot make any changes to the table in access).
The report has a text box which takes each row in the table and displays it in the text box and later prints it. I want to add a "*" at the beginning and end of the string and then display it in the text box.

I have done this so far:
- Choose data source (excel linked table) from report view
- In design view, press alt+F8 and drag and drop the column header I want into the report.

When I run the report it shows the report on each page, one page for every row of data which I will print later.

Now in design view after clicking on the text box, I go to property sheet and then the "Data" tab, if I try to change the expression to:
="*" & [tablename].[headername] & "*"
EDIT: There is an "asterisk" sign between the " " above, i don't know why they don't show.
When I run the report it asks me the parameter for the row number I want and displays the report only for that row. How can I use an expression and still be able to get all rows in the report in different pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did what I didn't want to in order to get the problem solved. I used a query to add an additional column (using an expression) and used the query as my data source. Doesn't look like there is a good way to use the report to directly make changes to the table data and show it in a textbox.